# Accessing properties in viewDidLoad vs viewWillAppear vs viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, lifecycle

I have a detail view which is being loaded into an UIViewScroll. As a part of loading it into the scroll view I set few properties on the detail view e.g. button (UIButton) and trip (NSString).

```
[controller.button setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[controller setTrip:[tripIDs objectForKey:[sortedTrips objectAtIndex:page]]];
```

Now in the detail controller I try to read those properties in three different methods

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
        NSLog(@"Button text %@",[[[self button] titleLabel]text]);
        NSLog(@"Trip text %@",[self trip] text]);    
}
```

I only get property values when I read in the viewDidAppear, for viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear all I get is null.

Why is that? And also where should I read and write those detail view properties *before* they appear on the screen so the user does not see text changing after the view loads?

Thanks for all your help!

Adding the trip declaration from details controller.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *trip;
```

Comment: Did you connect the outlets properly?

Comment: Yes, the IBOutlets are connected to the right XIB controls

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `UIButton` problem, the issue is that you cannot refer to the controller's views controls *prior* to `viewDidLoad`. So if you created the controller than then tried to set the button's title immediately, for example, that will not work because the view has not been created yet. In fact, if you look at the value of `controller.button` when you're doing your `setTitle` method call, I suspect you'll see that it is `nil`. Bottom line, one view controller should never try to access the view controls belonging to another view controller.

What you need to do is create `NSString` properties in your destination controller that you set when you first instantiate the view controller. Then `viewDidLoad` should do the `setTitle`, setting the title to the value you stored in the `NSString` property.

Regarding your `trip` variable, it's harder to figure out what's going on there, as your invocation of `setTrip` method (which suggests that `trip` is a `NSString` is not consisted with your `NSLog` statement of the `trip` property. Ignoring the fact that you have a mismatched `]` in the `NSLog` of trip, you're also using a `text` method which is what you'd do if `trip` was a `UILabel`, for example. But `NSString` objects don't have a `text` method.. You might need to share your declaration of the `trip` property for us to help you more on that one. But if it's an `IBOutlet`, too, then the problem is likely to be the same as my prior discussion about `button`.

Returning to the question about `viewDidLoad` v `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`, it really doesn't matter. Your properties should be accessible in all three. As a matter of practice, people generally use `viewDidLoad` unless necessitated by something else (e.g. timers or some animation is often best done in `viewDidAppear`), but you haven't articulated anything in your question that would suggest that `viewDidLoad` wouldn't be fine in this case.

But as I said, I suspect the problem is that your code that created `controller` is also trying to access some of its `IBOutlet` objects, which you cannot do. Or, potentially, your outlets are not hooked up properly.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Changed the code to pass a NSString to the detail controller from the parent controller. Added a '@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *buttonLabel' to the detail controller. Then call the '[controller setButtonLabel:destinationToText]' to set it in the parent controller. Next in the detail controller's viewDidLoad '[[self button] setTitle:buttonLabel forState:UIControlStateNormal]'. When I check buttonLabel is still nil in the viewDidLoad. But when I do '[[self button] setTitle:buttonLabel forState:UIControlStateNormal]' the UI populates with the buttonLabel. Magic?

Comment: Trip is declared as @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *trip;

Comment: @FireFly Regarding your comment about `buttonLabel` being `nil`, I don't if you've defined both the `@property` as well as explicitly declaring an class instance variable. You should _not_ declare instance variables for your properties, but let the compiler synthesize those for you. And either use `@synthesize buttonLabel = _buttonLabel;` or omit the `@synthesize` statement altogether (in which case it does the same thing, automatically synthesizing ivar with leading underscore).

Comment: @FireFly Regarding your comment about `trip` being defined a `NSString`, the `NSLog` statement `NSLog(@"Trip text %@",[self trip] text]);` doesn't make sense. Missing a `[`, but also `NSString` doesn't have a `text` method/property, so I would have thought that that line would generate a compiler warning at the least, and a runtime exception certainly. That `NSLog` statement is how you'd log the text of a `UILabel`, but you're telling us that `trip` is a `NSString`, not a `UILabel`, so I'm not sure how to reconcile your claim that `trip` is `NSString` with your `NSLog` statement.